# Perform merge between views of two or more modules

Tags: php, phalcon, volt, modularization

I have a Phalcon PHP modular application. I am making an administrative interface to control which modules should be used in the system.
One module controls the application's default interface, while the other modules add functionalities.

I have the problem: when another module to enabled, it can add the HTML content to the other interface control module. In this way I would like to merge two or more views. I am using Volt as template engine.

Is this possible in Phalcon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

<sup>**Note:** This was asked on the official Phalcon forums. I answered it over there and it got accepted. I am just mirroring my answer so future readers can get an answer here without being redirected from StackOverflow. Phalcon forum mirror: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/15891/perform-merge-between-views-of-two-or-more-modules</sup>

---

**config.php**

You will need to define your modules in the `app/config/config.php` file like so;

```
return new \Phalcon\Config([
// ...
    'modules' => [
        'module01',
        'module02',
        ...
        'moduleN',
    ],
// ...
]);
```

***Controller.php**

Then, in your controller, you'd set a view property to store the active modules like so;

```
$this->view->modules_enabled = $this->di->get("config")->modules;
```

***.volt**

And finally in your volt file, just check the module is in the array holding active modules, and if so, display the view using [partials](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.2/reference/views.html#using-partials).

```
{% if module01 in modules_enabled %}
   <div id="module">{{ partial("partials/module01") }}</div>
{% endif %}
```